# LINQ results change at end of for loop

Tags: c#, linq

When performing a set of LINQ queries against a data-source (I'm using LINQ-to-SQL, but it happens here too using just a `List<string>` object), I end up getting a different result at the end of my checks.

Specifically, the code below is trying to find if a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) either exists in a list of host names (not all of which will be FQDNs or in the same domain, but the host identifier is what matters to me). The search is trying to find whether `"host-6.domain.local"` or any of its sub-components exist (i.e, `"host-6.domain"` or `"host-6"`) in the list, which they do not. While inside the for-loop, we get the results we expect, but as soon as the for loop is finished, I get a result that has *all* of the contents of the list, which to me sounds like it is trying to find elements that match the empty string.

```
void MyMethod()  
{  
    string fqdn = "host-6.domain.local";  
    string[] splitFqdn = fqdn.Split('.');  
    List<string> values = new List<string>();  
    values.add("host-1");  
    values.add("host-2.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-3.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-4");  
    values.add("host-5.other.local");  
    IEnumerable<string> queryResult = null;  
    for (int i = splitFqdn.Length; i > 0; i--)  
    {  
        result =  
            from value in values  
            where value.StartsWith(  
                string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i)))  
            select value;  
        Console.WriteLine(  
            "Inside for loop, take " + i + ": "  + result.Count());  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine();  
    Console.WriteLine(  
        "Outside for loop: " + result.Count());  
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I get accurate results that I can still access after the for loop is finished?

Comment: When the loop exits, `i` will be equal to 0, which makes all values match (they all start with the empty string) Since `result` is lazily evaluated, that's what `results.Count()` will count after the loop has exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting bitten by LINQ's lazy execution and closure.

When you create an enumerable like you are doing here...

```
result =  
    from value in values  
    where value.StartsWith(  
        string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i)))  
    select value;
```

It doesn't get evaluated until you do something that forces it to get evaluated... for instance when you do `result.count()`

Then later outside of your loop when you evaluate it again `result.count()` is evaluated with the last value of i that existed in your for loop which is not giving you what you want.

Try forcing evaluation by doing `.ToList()` on your enumerable like so...  This code shows both values so you can compare.

```
void MyMethod()  
{  
    string fqdn = "host-6.domain.local";  
    string[] splitFqdn = fqdn.Split('.');  
    List<string> values = new List<string>();  
    values.add("host-1");  
    values.add("host-2.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-3.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-4");  
    values.add("host-5.other.local");  
    IEnumerable<string> queryResult = null;
    List<string> correctResult = null;
    for (int i = splitFqdn.Length; i > 0; i--)  
    {  
        queryResult =  
            from value in values  
            where value.StartsWith(  
                string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i)))  
            select value;
        correctResult = queryResult.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(  
            "Inside for loop, take " + i + ": "  + queryResult.Count());  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine();  
    Console.WriteLine(  
        "Outside for loop queryResult: " + queryResult.Count());  
    Console.WriteLine(  
        "Outside for loop correctResult: " + correctResult.Count());  
}
```

**EDIT: Thanks nlips** for pointing out that I hadn't fully answered the question...  and apologies for converting to method syntax but it would have taken longer to convert to query syntax.

```
void MyMethod()  
{
    string fqdn = "host-6.domain.local";
    string[] splitFqdn = fqdn.Split('.');
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    values.Add("host-1");
    values.Add("host-2.domain.local");
    values.Add("host-3.domain.local");
    values.Add("host-4");
    values.Add("host-5.other.local");
    values.Add("host-5.other.local");
    IEnumerable<string> queryResult = null;
    List<string> correctResult = new List<string>();
    for (int i = splitFqdn.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        correctResult = correctResult
            .Union(values.Where(
                value => value.StartsWith(string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i)))))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I think that @Sam want the union of all the result. So you need write `correctResult = correctResult.Union(queryResult)`. Moreover, queryResult should be declared within the loop. Out the loop i is considered to have the value 0 and so queryResult is considered to: `from value in values where value.StartsWith("") select value`

Comment: @nlips, I forgot to put it in my question, but I actually break the loop if a match is found. Thanks for pointing out the union option though!

Answer (score 2):

I really like Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542326/2175939) to my question, but I wasn't a huge fan of calling `.ToList()` on the result since this would cause all of the objects that matched to be pulled from the database (eating up more memory) rather than executing a query that simply got the count of matching objects (which is a little faster and doesn't take the memory to store the objects), so using the information from his post, I have this additional solution that doesn't require pulling all objects from a database, and only runs a COUNT query (in the SQL sense).

To avoid the issue caused by capturing `i` which then becomes `0` at the end of the for-loop, I simply set up a temporary variable to hold the value I'm searching for.

```
void MyMethod()  
{  
    string fqdn = "host-6.domain.local";  
    string[] splitFqdn = fqdn.Split('.');  
    List<string> values = new List<string>();  
    values.add("host-1");  
    values.add("host-2.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-3.domain.local");  
    values.add("host-4");  
    values.add("host-5.other.local");  
    IEnumerable<string> queryResult = null;  
    for (int i = splitFqdn.Length; i > 0; i--)  
    {  
        //taking the line referencing i out of the 
        //query expression prevents referencing i
        //after it is set to 0 outside the for loop
        string temp = string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i));
        //since temp isn't changed anywhere else, it won't
        //get set to an invalid value after the loop exits
        result =  
            from value in values  
            where value.StartsWith(temp)  
            select value;  
        Console.WriteLine(  
            "Inside for loop, take " + i + ": "  + result.Count());  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine();  
    Console.WriteLine(  
        "Outside for loop: " + result.Count());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `ToList` when assigning to the result variable like this:

```
result =  
            (from value in values  
            where value.StartsWith(  
                string.Join(".", splitFqdn.Take(i)))  
            select value).ToList();
```